# React Hook Form with AsyncSelect from React-Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form

working on an issue with the react-select AsyncSelect component that loads options from an API.But I can't pass the information to React-Hook Form through the controller.AsyncSelect works perfectly. The data goes back well in my "SelelectedValue" state. Can anyone help me ?

```
    const [inputValue, setValue] = useState('');
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null);
    // handle input change event
    const handleInputChange = value => {
        setValue(value);
    };
    // handle selection
    const handleChange = value => {
        setSelectedValue(value);
    }
```

```
const loadOptions = async (inputValue, callback) => {
 
        const response = await fetch(`APIurl`);
        const json = await response.json();
        const object = json.records;
        callback(object.map(i => ({ label: `${i.fields.firstName} - ${i.fields.lasName} , value: i.fields.firstName })))
    }
```

```
<Controller
   name="company"
   control={control}
   rules={{ required: true }}
   render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
       <AsyncSelect
         isClearable
         value={selectedValue}
         placeholder={'Your information'}
         loadOptions={loadOptions}
         onInputChange={handleInputChange}
         onChange={handleChange}
         styles={customStyles}
       />)}
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`react-hook-form` manages some common event and state (like value, onChange, onBlur etc.) for you so there is no need to define your own state in most case except `onInputChange` in `AsyncSelect`.

You can try to select the option and submit the form.

```js
<Controller
    name="company"
    control={control}
    rules={{ required: true }}
    render={({ field }) => (
    <AsyncSelect
        {...field}
        isClearable
        defaultOptions
        placeholder={"Your information"}
        loadOptions={loadOptions}
        onInputChange={handleInputChange}
        // styles={customStyles}
    />
    )}
/>
```

[Here is the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-franklin-jcxmf?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: hi, how does this work with `async multi select`? `onInputChange` only captures the `key-in` input and Not the `selected` options array object?